# How does Ident_current() work

Tags: sql-server

Where does the Ident_Current() get its return value?

I would like to find the system table(s) that hold identity values.  Any information on HOW ident_current works would also be helpful.

Please note that I understand what ident_current does, I just don't know where it gets its value or how it does it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/scope-identity-vs-ident-current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do exactly what `IDENT_CURRENT()` does because what it does is not officially documented. You can get the same answer - simulating what `IDENT_CURRENT()` does - from:

```
SELECT COALESCE(last_value, seed_value)
  FROM sys.identity_columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.tablename'));
```

Which [I answered in your other question 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042439/which-is-faster-max-or-ident-current).

If you want to test how fast `IDENT_CURRENT` is, then test `IDENT_CURRENT`, don't try to simulate its functionality, because that won't necessarily be a valid test of what `IDENT_CURRENT` does (for example, it can probably retrieve these from memory, while you can't).

Comment: Aaron - Thank you for the information - this is what I was looking for.  I marked the question as answered.